# Unable to call ruby lambda

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm having issue in calling ruby lambda as below.

I'm having a function which accepts a `Proc`. And lambda definition as below.

```
def call_proc_with_arg(&b)
   b.call(1)
end

lam = -> (a) { puts "printing the argument #{a}"}
```

And when I try to pass the lambda to function as,

```
call_proc_with_arg(lam)
```

I'm getting the error,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 6: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>' 5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in` load'
> 4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>' 3: from (irb):118 2: from (irb):118:in` rescue in irb_binding'
> 1: from (irb):52:in `call_block'
> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))

Whereas the function works with block,

```
call_proc_with_arg {|a| puts "printing the argument #{a}"}
```

What am I missing with lambda?

Comment: what's `call_block`?

Comment: That is supposed to be `call_proc_with_arg`. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: 2 options: (1) Remove the `&` from `&b`, or (2) Add `&` to `lam`: `call_proc_with_arg(&lam)`

Comment: FYI: since you are getting an argument error on `call_proc_with_arg(lam)` already, the problem is not _calling_ the lambda but _passing_ the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following syntax to call the method passing the block, as you defined `b` as block in the method signature:

```
call_proc_with_arg(&lam)
```

The only way you could use `call_proc_with_arg(lam)` is if you treat the argument not as a method block, but as a first-class argument:

```
def call_proc_with_arg(b)
   b.call(1)
end

call_proc_with_arg(lam)
```

Each syntax has its own advantage/disadvantage, and it depends on the use case. If you want to leverage blocks, then the first one is the most common one. In such case, you can also use a more common `yield` syntax:

```
def call_proc_with_arg(&b)
   yield 1
end
```

instead of referencing the block `b` variable directly.

The second one would be necessary if you want to pass more than one lambda as parameter, as a single method cannot take multiple blocks.

Comment: With `yield` you can omit `&b`

Answer (score 1):

You can call it different ways

```
lam = -> (a) { puts "printing the argument #{a}"}
```

```
# method with parameter as lambda
def call_proc_with_arg(b)
  b.call(1)
end

call_proc_with_arg(lam)
```

```
# method without parameters
def call_proc_with_arg
  yield 1
end

call_proc_with_arg(&lam)
```

```
# method without parameters with named block
def call_proc_with_arg(&b)
  b.call(1)
end

call_proc_with_arg(&lam)
```